# Spyder IDE won't open

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, spyder

so I had Python 3.7.0 and my Spyder IDE was working fine.
However, because there was no version of tensorflow for that version of python I decided to downgrade my python to version 3.5.0.
Now realising that was a trade-off, I'm assuming there's a correlation there because my  Spyder IDE no longer launches, neither does my Anaconda Navigator.
I have already done a Spyder --reset command by the way, no luck.
How can I fix this issue while maintaining to use tensorflow?

Comment: How exactly did you "downgrade" python?

Comment: Uninstalled 3.7.0 for 3.5.0 @merv

Comment: Did you use `conda`? or a downloaded installer?

Comment: I used conda to install the python package